# Visual Studio 2022 Console App: debugger exits with code -1 when using `FileReader` in *unrelated* React app

Tags: c#, reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net-core

This is really baffling me.

I have a Visual Studio 2022 console application (it is actually a .NET 6 Minimal API, which is implemented as a console app).

*Separately*, I have a React TypeScript app running in VS Code and inside a different repository.  The app utilizes the node module `FileReader` to read files from my local machine.  It is defined as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const handleFile = (e: any) => {
    const content = e.target.result;
    console.log('file content',  content)
  }
  
  const handleChangeFile = (file: any) => {
    let fileData = new FileReader();
    fileData.onloadend = handleFile;
    fileData.readAsText(file);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input type="file" accept=".txt" onChange={e => {
            if (e?.target?.files) {
            handleChangeFile(e.target.files[0])
            }
        }} /> 
     </div>      
    </div>
  );
}
```

What happens is: when my .NET app is running in VS in debug mode, and when my React app is also running, if I use the `FileReader` via the UI in Chrome as follows:

[image]

The .NET app exits suddenly as soon as I have finished selecting the file!

The console looks like this:

[image]

It makes no sense to me at all!  How could a Node/React app, running as a separate process in a separate repo, cause a .NET app running/debugging in Visual Studio to crash?  The React app isn't calling any endpoints in my .NET API, and in fact isn't communicating at all with it.

What is going on here?

Comment: The FileReader is reading from the `<input type="file">` element in your browser, to which you are uploading the file. The FileReader has no way to read from your local disk directly. Besides that, it's the Console (API) App that exits so we need to see what is in it. Does it read, write or monitor the same file perhaps?

Comment: Hi @peter-b there are no shared directories/files between the webapp and the console app.  `FileReader` is reading from a separate directory, and is successfully reading the files and extracting their text content.  Could the underlying (server-side) `nodejs` or `react` libraries that handle I/O be conflicting with the VS debugger?  (Incidentally, everything works fine if I run the console app's `.exe` directly versus running it inside Visual Studio).

Comment: With a typical React setup, Node only runs to compile/transpile the React app to JS, and then it presumably starts a web server that hosts the resulting JS files. The JS then runs in the browser and Node has no further involvement with what you do with the app running in the browser. From this perspective I can't explain what is happening and we need more details, esp. about the .NET app about which you still have not shared any details with us.

Comment: this is really weird and I have several questions about it. First of all, according to your description, it looks like the API app is not related to the react client app, then why we need to run the API project so that it would be stopped when react app is trying to read file? The second question is that, do we have any error messages from the API app? for example, in event viewer, can we see some related error messages?

Comment: The API app is a .NET 6 solution that includes, among other things, an AWS Serverless (SAM) Lambda function app and a .NET "minimal API".  I am using the minimal API as the startup project.  The React app will eventually call the minimal API's endpoints, but is currently now doing so (until I resolve this issue).  There are no relevant entries in the  Windows Event Viewer - just the "exited with code -1" message in the Terminal and the VS Output pane.  BTW, I've discovered that this failure happens only when React uses Chrome (Edge doesn't cause this problem).

Comment: it's hard to start an investigation now .. Browser related issue? But Edge is also using Chrome as the core...